# Want to save only year from timestamp in database

Tags: php, sql, codeigniter, phpmyadmin

I want to save  only year in my database as `date_created` with type `currenttimestamp`

I'm getting the value of the year from a `select` html.
After getting the value, i will transfer it to the controller

Here's my code

```
$registered_year = sanitize($this->input->post('registered_year'));
$registered_year2 =". $registered_year .-00-00 00:00:00";
$app_type = 1;
$ref_no = generate_reference_number();

$this->Model->dealer_renew_save($account_id,$req_id,$ref_no,$app_type,$registered_year2);

$data = [
         'success'=>1,
         'message'=> 'Application Successfully Renewed.'
         ];

generate_json($data);
```

For example, I chose `2018` then I want it to save `2018-00-00 00:00:00`

it saves `0000-00-00 00:00:00`

What seems to be the problem?

Comment: it should like $registered_year2 = $registered_year . "-00-00 00:00:00"; Problem in passing year to db just print before insert.

Comment: have you tried to check if  `$this->input->post('registered_year')` has value?

Comment: Why not to change the datatype of this entity to `datetime()` instead of generating manual date and time?

Comment: @DevsiOdedra it still saves 0000-00-00 but the value of registered_year2 is 2010-00-00 00:00:00. Btw, my date_created type is currenttimestamp.

Comment: Why when you can do `YEAR(created)` on a datetime field.

Comment: The problem is your date is this `$registered_year2 =". $registered_year .-00-00 00:00:00";` or if the `$registered_year=2019`  then you have `.2019.-00-00 00:00:00` with dots.  Your mixing concatenation up with interpolation.

Comment: @Roshan yes mate. It has value.

Comment: @ArtisticPhoenix I already did $registered_year2 = $registered_year."-00-00 00:00:00"); and i check the string using print_r and it has 2018-00-00 00:00:00 but still it saves 00-00-00 00:00:00.

Comment: problem in data type.

Comment: Well I don't think `2019-00-00` is a valid date either.  That was just the obvious thing.

Comment: use datetime data type instead of timestamp.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is your date is this

```
$registered_year2 =". $registered_year .-00-00 00:00:00";
```

See if `$registered_year=2019` then you have `. 2019 .-00-00 00:00:00` with dots. Your mixing concatenation up with interpolation.  And MySQL date time does not recognize that as a valid date.

> For example, i chose 2018 then i want to save it 2018-00-00 00:00:00

Well to be sure, `2018-00-00 00:00:00` is not `. 2019 .-00-00 00:00:00`

It's a simple typo.

*Further*

`2018-00-00 00:00:00` is not a valid date.  So that wont work.  But lets look at this:

> want to save year only in my database date_created with type currenttimestamp

Datetime is not a timestamp. And if you need the year from a datetime field you can use `YEAR(datetime_field)` in both the select and where parts of the query.

If you need it from a timestamp, you can cast the timestamp to a DateTime

```
   YEAR(FROM_UNIXTIME(timestamp_field))
```

So if you save the current datetime (NOW()) even though I prefer doing this in PHP because the DB has it's own timezone setting separate from PHP. Then you can just do that when you need the year.

Cheers.

Comment: Got it mate. Then I changed the type from timestamp into datetime. Thanks mate

Comment: You can use either one, timestamp or datetime, they both have advantages in some situations.  For created at, I would probably use a datetime, just because it's easier to read ... lol

Answer (score 0):

There are two things to chage. 1st as per the ArtisticPhoenix answer

```
$registered_year2 = $registered_year . "-00-00 00:00:00";
```

make sure that date is `2018-00-00 00:00:00`

Another thing is that change your field **type** from `timestamp` to `datetime`